# How to get animate to work on an accordion menu?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm trying to get an animation to work when I delete a section of an accordion.  Instead of just disappearing, I'd like it to do something super duper cool.  How do I get animate to work in this instance?  Thanks a bunch.  Here is my JS:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('#accordion .red').click(function(){

    $(this).parent('div').prev( 'h3' ).remove();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    $(this).parent('div').prev('div').animate("bounceslide");

    return false;
  });
});
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">

    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div class="squares">
            <a href="#" class="green">1</a>
            <a href="# "class="red">2</a>
            <a href="#" class="blue">3</a>  
            <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
            </p>
    </div>

    <h3><a href="#">Section 1</a></h3>
    <div class="squares">
            <a href="#" class="green">1</a>
            <a href="# "class="red">2</a>
            <a href="#" class="blue">3</a>  
            <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
            ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
            amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
            odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
            </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this *super duper-ness* you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/gaM4C/ `:)`

Comment: Thanks but that's a little too super duper.  I just need it to work when I delete a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bit of a flaw in your logic as it currently stands...
You call:

```
$(this).parent('div').remove();
```

And then:

```
$(this).parent('div').prev('div').animate("bounceslide");
```

Because `$(this)` no longer exists in the DOM (it was removed along with its' parent), your above selector won't work.

I would suggest using an animation callback to remove the accordion item after your *super duper cool* stuff.
Something like:

```
$('#accordion .red').click(function(){
  var $toRemove = $(this).parent('div').prev('h3');
      $toRemove = $toRemove.add($(this).parent('div'));

  $toRemove.animate({height:0}, 500, function(){
    // This is the callback.
    $toRemove.remove();
  });

  return false;
});
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L9BXS/

Comment: +1 will get you <= 5K and also for bit of explanation bruver! `:)`

Comment: I see my error in logic, but ur code doesn't seem to be having any effect.  Thanks a bunch anyways.  I'm sure I'm just making another dumb error. :/

Comment: @user1179593 - I've made a JSfiddle to show you: http://jsfiddle.net/L9BXS/  -  so it should work =) Anything in the error console for you?

Comment: Yeah, an unexpected identifier on this line:  var $toRemove = $(this).parent('div').prev('h3');

Comment: @user1179593 - did you forget the `{` ? Check the line before.

Comment: Ha! I got it! First there was some copy and paste weirdness and than it wasn't all wrapped in $('document').ready(function{});  Thanks a bunch.  I'm obviously a nube. :)

Comment: @user1179593 - Well done for working it out! That's the best way to learn.